# How to inform Cordova where to find shared libraries for building a project?

Tags: cordova

(Skill level: Trying to understand Cordova for the first time)

Cordova, by definition, expects my mobile app to be a mini website stored inside the 'www' folder of the newly created Cordova project; with its own javascript folder (named 'js').

**Question**: There are four Javascript files that are common and shared among several of my projects. Is there a way for Cordova to include those files at the very last minute during a build (just like it does for the cordova.js file) instead of me having to copy/paste them multiple times in the 'js' folder of each project ?

Note: These shared files are local and when they get updated they are meant to affect every project that relies on them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sharedCore01.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sharedCore02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sharedCore03.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sharedCore04.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/projectSpecific.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a before_build hook to automatically copy your js files in your poject each time you build.

Check the hook doc page for more info : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/